# What is the most efficient way to handle a layer/image type?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, vector

[Code can be found under src/ from here.](https://github.com/Cave-Dweller/CaveArt/tree/dev)

The way I have the pixel types set up is to have the bit depth-specific formats be used for loading images and serialization, and the float-based pixel type would be used to actually be modified and for conversion between the depth-specific types.

Conceptually, `Layer` should hold the data relevant to the application (to be modified), but my issue is with efficiency with different areas- should I have `Layer` hold a two-dimensional pointer to the `PixelBase` type for easy loading and serialization, but ugly and seemingly inefficient conversion and modification (and also manual memory management), or should I hold a `std::vector<std::vector<PixelRGBAF>>` for simple conversion and modification, but seemingly ugly and inefficient loading and serialization?

Examples of what I mean:

```
class Layer {
    PixelBase** data;
    int width, height;
    //...
public:
    Layer(QImage& qi) {
        width = qi.width();
        height = qi.height();
        if(qi.format() == QImage::Format_RGBA8888) {
            data = new PixelRGBA32[height];
            for(int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
                data[i] = new PixelRGBA32[width];
            }
            //...
            for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
                    QRgb temp = qi.pixel(x, y);
                    data[y][x] = PixelRGBA32{ temp.red(), temp.green(), temp.blue(), temp.alpha()};    //data is used once in initialization
                }
            }
        }
        //...
    }
};
```

versus

```
class Layer {
    std::vector<std::vector<PixelRGBAF>> data;
    int width, height;
    //...
public:
    Layer(QImage& qi) {
        width = qi.width();
        height = qi.height();
        if(qi.format() == QImage::Format_RGBA8888) {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
                    QRgb temp = qi.pixel(x, y);
                    PixelRGBA32 prgba= PixelRGBA32{ temp.red(), temp.green(), temp.blue(), temp.alpha()};    //this data is used once and thrown away, is an extra step in initialization
                    data[y][x] = prgba.getAsDepthAgnostic();    //data is copied into a larger chunk of data (32 * 4 instead of 8 * 4)
                }
            }
        }
        //...
    }
};
```

I do want a scripting language I'm building to interact with layers directly in the future, so in my thinking, using the `vector<vector<PixelRGBAF>>` option would be better in terms of efficiency for most use, but I have a feeling I'm skipping over some important detail and it's actually less efficient.

Comment: It depends on which actions are performed more frequently. And why QImage doesn't satisfy your needs?

Comment: The most frequent actions would be pixel manipulations (setting, blending, accessing values, etc.). QImage does actually meet my needs, but it also exceeds them extensively. I'm not using pure Qt because with this image editor, I want to keep the back end and front end as separated as possible, I'm going to try to attach a scripting language to it to make tool/filter/function creation easier, and I want as little extra connected to it as possible. So this code acts as a translator between the two. I also want to have the ability to quickly switch to another platform if a better one pops up.

Comment: To clarify and expand on that last comment, it basically comes down to keeping my own logical system clean outside influence or getting too committed to a single platform. I want to have my own design be as simple as possible, and while Qt has many features, it's also quite complex as a result. I'm only really using it for interaction and loading up images to convert to my own format. My format will be used to modify and access the pixels at runtime, and will later be converted back to a QImage for serialization.